# How to allow an svg to appear on a div element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

At the moment I have implemented an svg using the svg.js library. The circle "draw_face" is being drawn on the canvas id which is an SVG not a div. by calling .draggable(), the shape can be dragged anywhere on the "canvas". however I want to drag it into the "save" div aswell so that I can save all the svg elements within that div as a .xml or .svg file. By adding ForeignObject, the circle goes on top of the div, however the div does not recognise that the circle is inside the div. when I try to save the results within the div when the circle is on top of it, a blank page gets saved. How can I make the div recognise that there is circle inside it so that I can save the file.

```
        #canvas {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #cccccc;
        }

        #save{
            background-color: #ff0000;
              width: 550px;
              height: 490px;
        }

        <svg id = "canvas" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" z-index="100">
            <svg id = "droparea" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1100 1100" z-index="100">
                <foreignObject x="520" y="20" width="550" height="485">
                   <div id = "save">
                   </div>
                </foreignObject>
           </svg>
       </svg>

var canvas = SVG('canvas');
       function face_draw() {
           var face = canvas.circle(30).attr({ fill: '#f4e3d7', stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width':0.15}).move(15,15);
           face.draggable();
       }

    face_draw();
```

Comment: Hard to tell what you really want to achieve:/ you need to provide more context. In your small code you have a div inside of svg space - that won’t work. Replace div with svg container element - <g>

Comment: Okay, I have added more context to my code, please feel free to look. thank you

Comment: OK I did your job for your question;) is this what your case is: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmu56awz/3809/ (not yet the answer) Can you clarify what exactly you wanted to achieve - to be able to drag "circles" from blue div into the svg space?

Answer (score 0):

So if you meant you are trying to be able to drag circles from the container (div you target) into the grey SVG area as you can see in the fiddle I provided in comments, and you think it is a z-index issue - it is **not**.

SVG space and HTML space are different as well as two SVG spaces are independent (unless nested) and you will not really achieve what you want via z-index - the circles right now can not be rendered outside of one SVG space that SVG.js is creating for you inside DIV and they just get "culled".

The reason you are not getting a "nested" SVG scenario here is cause of "divs" - they are not part of SVG name space.

If you could describe your end-goal - it is possible to work around it:
- you could "wrap" or find better technique to nest SVG spaces (using foreignObject etc)

I would use only one SVG space for such manipulation:

HTML:

```
<body>
<svg id = "canvas" width="400px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 400 100" style="background-color: #cccccc">
    <g id = "save" width="200px" height="100px">
      <rect width="200px" height="100px" fill="red"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = SVG('save');

function face_draw() {
    var face = canvas.circle(30).attr({ fill: '#f4e3d7', stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width':0.15}).move(15,15);
  face.draggy();
}
face_draw();
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please view it and hopefully it will help you solve my problem? I have made use of foreign object. it only renders the  div on top of the svg object, it doesnt allow the svg shape to go inside it when dragged.

Comment: Hey @pinda can you create a fiddle with your working code? its very hard to help you by trying to recreate how your code works just based off your code alone;/

Comment: I think I know what you need. So you basically you want the circles to be inside the div so that you could capture SVG/XML as file - correct?

Comment: Another question - any reason why can't you just grab svg element with id "canvas" to get what you want?

Comment: I was struggling to make the fiddle due to the face that I have never used it before and my circle was not rendering in javascript. However yes you are right, I do want the circles to be inside the div but only after it has been dragged from its default position, which is the svg "canvas" id.