# how to drag an svg shape into another svg so that it can be saved

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have imported a library from "svg.js" called "svg.draggable" so that I can drag SVG shapes on the webpage. I am trying to make a toolkit where the user can make his own faces. For example, there will be a set of heads that the user can choose from. There will be a set of eyes from where the user can choose from. So far you can choose which type of head or eyes you want and drag it onto a new SVG rectangle to see how the face looks like. I want to save everything that has been dragged into the new SVG, however, the SVG saves a blank page because it does not recognize the shapes being dragged into it. How can I make the shapes be dragged into the new SVG so that it can save everything that has entered it?
Below is an example of my code so far:

```
<style>
   #canvas {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    #save{
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 550px;
    height: 490px;
    overflow: visible;
    }
</style>
   <svg id = "canvas" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" z-index="100">

            <svg id = "droparea" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1100 1100" z-index="100">
               <foreignObject x="520" y="20" width="550" height="485">
                  <svg id = "save">


                  </svg>
               </foreignObject>
            </svg>
   </svg>

<script>
    var canvas = SVG('canvas');

    // function to save everything in the tag
    function saveSvgAsFile()
    {
        var textToSave = save.innerHTML
        //---or use this---
        //var textToSave = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(mySVG)

        var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/xml"});
        var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
        var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
        downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

        downloadLink.click();
    }

    function destroyClickedElement(event)
    {
        document.body.removeChild(event.target);
    }

    // function to draw the head
    function face_draw() {
    var face = canvas.circle(30).attr({ fill: '#f4e3d7', stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width':0.15}).move(15,15);
    face.draggable();
    }
<script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here is a JSFiddle with your current code to start you off: https://jsfiddle.net/euz19d5t/

Comment: I have updated the code, please find it on: https://jsfiddle.net/lallr/euz19d5t/7/   I ant to be able to drag the circle into the red box so that I can save the results as an .svg or .xml. However when I save it at the moment, it only saves a blank page because the circle does not directly go into the new svg.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow an svg to appear on a div element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692724/how-to-allow-an-svg-to-appear-on-a-div-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things were needed to make this work:

1. When it looks like you drag the circle into the red `#save` SVG, you're actually only dragging it **on top of** that box. The circle is still only a child of the `#canvas` SVG. You need to detect when the circle is dropped inside the `#save` area, and then move it from `#canvas` to `#save` yourself.

   - *Look at the new `dragIntoBoard()` function, it does this by measuring where the mouse pointer is when the circle is dropped.*
2. When reading the SVG xml for saving, you need to use `XMLSerializer` instead of `save.innerHTML`. `.innerHTML` would include all elements *inside* `#save`, but not the outer `<svg id="save">` root node.
3. To make your CSS apply to the exported SVG file, you need to put it in a `<style>` element inside the SVG:

   - `<svg id="save">
         <style>
             #save {
                 background-color: ...`

Updated pen: https://jsfiddle.net/euz19d5t/10/

Comment: Thank you very much it works. However when I drag onto the new SVG, it does not go exactly where I placed it. If you drag it too far, it goes off the webpage and cannot be found. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Remove the `viewBox` on `#droparea` so that everything has the same scale (in fact, you can simplify the SVG structure even more, by removing both `#droparea` and `<foreignObject>`). Then, when the circle is dropped, adjust its x/y position which now needs to be relative to `#save`: https://jsfiddle.net/euz19d5t/12/

Comment: Perfect, it is working the way I want it to, thank you.

Comment: Great! Please [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Hello @Sphinxxx I was trying to resize a path (straight line), however when I do, it's x and y position changes. Is there a way to solve this?